# d3.js - connecting shapes with lines (without using force or other layouts)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of static circles and I want to connect them with lines (it's a dependency graph). All the examples I see are done with d3's ready-made layouts and I'm not sure how to approach this efficiently. I also want to highlight lines related to a node when I mouse-over that node, as well as fade any other shapes/lines.

This is what I have for now: (it just draws evenly spaced and sized circles according to area size given)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
     <div id="drawarea"  style="overflow: hidden;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">


var dataset = [],
    i = 0;

for(i=0; i<45; i++){
    dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
}    

 var   width = 5000,
       height = 3000;

var svg = d3.select("#drawarea").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .append("g");

var div_area = width*height,
    num_nodes = dataset.length,
    node_area = div_area/num_nodes*0.7,
    node_to_padding_ratio = 0.50,
    node_dia_inc_pad = Math.sqrt(node_area),
    node_radius_wo_pad = node_dia_inc_pad/2*node_to_padding_ratio,
    node_padding = node_dia_inc_pad/2*(1-node_to_padding_ratio),
    nodes_in_width = parseInt(width/(node_dia_inc_pad)),
    nodes_in_height = parseInt(height/(node_dia_inc_pad));  

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", node_radius_wo_pad)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+i%nodes_in_width*node_dia_inc_pad;})
    .attr("cy", function(d, i){ return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+(parseInt(i/nodes_in_width))*node_dia_inc_pad})
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})

function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** My revised code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden;">
         <div id="canvas"  style="overflow: hidden;"></div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
    var graph = {
      "nodes":[
        {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
        {"name":"Napoleon","group":1}
      ],
      "links":[
        {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}
      ]
    }


      var   width = 2000,
       height = 1000;

var svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .append("g");



var div_area = width*height,
    num_nodes = graph.nodes.length,
    node_area = div_area/num_nodes,
    node_to_padding_ratio = 0.50,
    node_dia_inc_pad = Math.sqrt(node_area),
    node_radius_wo_pad = node_dia_inc_pad/2*node_to_padding_ratio,
    node_padding = node_dia_inc_pad/2*(1-node_to_padding_ratio),
    nodes_in_width = parseInt(width/(node_dia_inc_pad)),
    nodes_in_height = parseInt(height/(node_dia_inc_pad));  


var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,nodes_in_width])
    .range([node_radius_wo_pad,width-node_radius_wo_pad]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,nodes_in_height])
    .range([node_radius_wo_pad,height-node_radius_wo_pad]);


var lines = svg.attr("class", "line")
  .selectAll("line").data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d.source%nodes_in_width); })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return yScale(parseInt(d.source/nodes_in_width)); })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.target%nodes_in_width); })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {  return yScale(parseInt(d.target/nodes_in_width)); })
  .attr("src", function(d) {  return d.source; })
  .attr("trgt", function(d) {  return d.target; })
  .style("stroke", "grey");

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", node_radius_wo_pad)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(i%nodes_in_width);})
    .attr("cy", function(d, i){ return yScale(parseInt(i/nodes_in_width));})
    .attr("index", function(d, i){return i;})
    .on("mouseover", function(){
        var that = this;
        lines.filter(function() {   
            return d3.select(this).attr("src") == d3.select(that).attr("index");
           }).style("stroke", "red");
        lines.filter(function() {
            return d3.select(this).attr("trgt") == d3.select(that).attr("index");
           }).style("stroke", "green");
        lines.filter(function() {
            return (d3.select(this).attr("trgt") != d3.select(that).attr("index") && d3.select(this).attr("src") != d3.select(that).attr("index"));
           }).style("display", "none");
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");
     })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
      lines.style("stroke", "grey")
           .style("display", "block");
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");
    });






function zoom() {
      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do now is have the circles the lines point to and from be colored similarly. I'm not sure how to make the reference to them from the "mouseover" event of a circle though. Will do some testing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified how your nodes are connected, so I'm assuming that everything is connected to everything. The principle is the same as for any other layout -- you take the data you have that determines the links and pass it to `.data()`. In your code, the coordinates aren't part of the data, which makes it a bit more verbose, but still quite straightforward.

To add the links, I'm using a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) -- I'm adding a `g` element for each node and underneath the connections to all the other nodes.

```
var lines = svg.selectAll("g.line").data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "line")
  .selectAll("line").data(dataset)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d, i) { return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+i%nodes_in_width*node_dia_inc_pad; })
  .attr("y1", function(d, i) { return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+(parseInt(i/nodes_in_width))*node_dia_inc_pad; })
  .attr("x2", function(d, i, j) { return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+j%nodes_in_width*node_dia_inc_pad; })
  .attr("y2", function(d, i, j) { return 2*node_radius_wo_pad+(parseInt(j/nodes_in_width))*node_dia_inc_pad; });
```

This adds a line for every pair of nodes. Note that it will add links between the same nodes (which you won't be able to see) and 2 links between each pair of nodes -- once starting at one node and once at the other. I haven't filtered out these cases here to keep the code simple. In your particular application, I'm guessing that the connections are determined in another way anyway.

To highlight the links that are connected a particular node on highlight, I'm using the `links` variable that contains all of them and filtering out the ones whose start coordinates are different from the coordinates of the circle. The filtered selection is then painted red.

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
   var that = this;
   lines.filter(function() {
       return d3.select(this).attr("x1") == d3.select(that).attr("cx") && d3.select(this).attr("y1") == d3.select(that).attr("cy");
     }).style("stroke", "red");
   d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");
})
```

If the coordinates are part of the data, everything will become a bit easier and look more like the examples you may have seen for the force layout for example. I would recommend to create a data structure much like what's used there for your links, with `source` and `target` attributes that determine the source and target nodes.

Complete example [here](https://vida.io/documents/WCNim8brbbcWAKNud).

Comment: lol, that's awesome! And yeah, I do have a structure just like that for the links. I won't lie, mind is semi-blown over what you did there, d3 seems so complicated...

Comment: I've edited my question with my new code and a new feature I want to implement, if you would like to take a look :)

Comment: You can filter the circles in the same way that the links are filtered. I would strongly recommend going with a data structure that contains the coordinate information though.